# Problem with chardev.c example from The Linux Kernel Module Programmers Guide

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I compiled and ran [the chardev.c](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x569.html) example from [the lkmpg](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/index.html) and when writing to the device received an unexpected error:

```
anon@anon:~/lkmpg$ sudo echo "hi" > /dev/chardev
bash: /dev/chardev: Permission denied
```

The module write function looks like this:

```
/*  
 * Called when a process writes to dev file: echo "hi" > /dev/chardev 
 */
static ssize_t
device_write(struct file *filp, const char *buff, size_t len, loff_t * off)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Sorry, this operation isn't supported.\n");
    return -EINVAL;
}
```

I'm not getting the expected error of invalid operation and the error printed to /var/log/messages.

I can read from the device with no problem, receiving the expected results:

```
anon@anon:~/lkmpg$ cat /dev/chardev 
I already told you 6 times Hello world!
```

The device /dev/chardev is created manually using:

```
sudo mknod /dev/chardev c 252 0
```

What's the deal?

**--Edit--**

Apparently when I mknod to create the device it ends up with the following permissions:

```
crw-r--r-- 1 root root 252, 0 2009-10-30 09:27 /dev/chardev.
```

Once I did `sudo chmod a+w /dev/chardev` the driver worked as expected.

However, people have said it is not correct to do this.

**What is the correct course of action and why?**

Comment: Can you post the full source code of your module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A really, really, really straight forward and simple example of how to implement character drivers can be found in `drivers/watchdog/softdog.c`

You can compare your code to this example, which shows you how to do the following:

- Read from the device
- Write to the device
- Present an ioctl interface via the device

While softdog is a very useful tool, its as much a tutorial as anything else. Alan Cox threw it together, so its a good example of more 'proper' implementation.

If you can post the whole source to your module, we can help you find out why your function is not being entered as expected.

***Update:***

It is *perfectly* acceptable to allow under privileged users to write to character devices! I repeat, it is **perfectly acceptable** to allow under privileged users to write to character devices! If this was not the case, stuff like FUSE, Modems, USB Gadgets, CD ROMS and other things would require root access to use.

What you can do is take advantage of *group* memberships. I.e., on Ubuntu, users permitted to use FUSE (file system in user space) should belong to the 'fuse' group, which permits granular access on who can and can not use that feature. Similarly, on some of my systems, a QRNG (quantum random number generator) is in use .. and is (you guessed it) a character device. I need to allow PHP to access that device , so I:

- Create a QRNG group
- Make sure PHP runs as the user (not anonymous system users)
- Add users owning apps that need access to the device to the QRNG group

I hope that clears it up :)

Comment: The source is at the bottom of the linked page: http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x569.html

Comment: Exactly what is softdog supposed to do?  Cause the system to reboot after a certain amount of time?

Comment: @Robert S Barnes: Once the watchdog device is opened, you will have to write to it every (xx) minutes, or the system reboots itself. You can also write a magic key "W"  to it if you want to stop the watchdog from monitoring.

Answer (score 4):

I think, actual problem is the command which you issued to write is incorrect. Try

`#sudo sh -c "echo "hi" > /dev/chardev"`

If you want to run multiple commands with sudo then you should use command as shown above. With this, you dont need to do chmod and change its permissions as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: No, it not just "echo", there is also a shell running to redirect the output of echo. With your command, the /bin/echo program is running as root, because of sudo, but the shell that's redirecting echo's output to the root-only file is still running as you. Your current shell does the redirection before sudo starts.
The solution is to run the whole pipeline under sudo.

Comment: @vinit:  Referring to your answer below, why should these devices only be accessible to root?  Aren't there situations where I may want a device that can be written by anyone?

Comment: For security reasons. Please refer to my comment on other answer for further explanation.

Comment: And a user space app that needs to open /dev/foo, get a FD and perform an ioctl() can do so using sudo how? Or, someone just hoping to use minicom to access a device attached to a serial port?

Comment: @vinit +1: even though it's not the answer I'm looking for it's still a very useful little trick to know.  Thanks!